# Why does my tcl regex perform so badly in comparison to perl?

Tags: regex, performance, perl, tcl

```
set fr [open "x.txt" r]
set fw [open "y.txt" w]
set myRegex {^([0-9]+) ([0-9:]+\.[0-9]+).* ABC\.([a-zA-Z]+)\[([0-9]+)\] DEF\(([a-zA-Z]+)\) HIJ\(([0-9]+)\) KLM\(([0-9\.]+)\) NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)}
while { [gets $fr line] >= 0 } {
   if { [regexp $myRegex $line match x y w z]} {
       if { [expr $D >> 32] == [lindex $argv 0]} {
         puts $fw "$x"
       }
   }
}
close $fr $fw
```

The above bit of tcl code takes forever (32s or more) to execute. Doing basically the same thing in perl runs in 3s or less. I know that perl performs better for some regex but will the tcl performance really be this bad in comparison? more than 10 times worse?

I'm using TCL 8.4 by the way

Here are the metrics of running the above code with the regex and with reduced versions of the same regex

```
32s is the time taken for the above code to execute
22s after removing: QRS\(([0-9]+)\) 
17s after removing: NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)
13s after removing: KLM\(([0-9\.]+)\) NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)
9s  after removing: HIJ\(([0-9]+)\) KLM\(([0-9\.]+)\) NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)
6s  after removing: DEF\(([a-zA-Z]+)\) HIJ\(([0-9]+)\) KLM\(([0-9\.]+)\) NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)}
```

Comment: Normally, slow regex are slow because they spend a lot of time backtracking, but this pattern does not suffer from that. (Backtracking leads to failure very quickly.) If I were to guess, Perl notice that a line can't match much faster than TCL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you have a lot of capturing and backtracking in that RE; that particular combination works poorly with the Tcl RE engine. The cause on one level is that Tcl uses a completely different type of RE engine to Perl (though it works better for other REs; this area is non-trivial).

If you can, get rid of that early `.*` from the RE:

```
^([0-9]+) ([0-9:]+\.[0-9]+).* ABC\.([a-zA-Z]+)\[([0-9]+)\] DEF\(([a-zA-Z]+)\) HIJ\(([0-9]+)\) KLM\(([0-9\.]+)\) NOP\(([0-9]+)\) QRS\(([0-9]+)\)
                           ^^
```

That's the real cause of trouble. Replace with something more exact, such as this:

```
(?:[^A]|A[^B]|AB[^C])*
```

Also, reduce the number of capturing groups in your RE to exactly those you need. You can probably convert the code overall to this:

```
set fr [open "x.txt" r]
set fw [open "y.txt" w]
set myRegex {^([0-9]+) (?:[0-9:]+\.[0-9]+)(?:[^A]|A[^B]|AB[^C])* ABC\.(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\[([0-9]+)\] DEF\((?:[a-zA-Z]+)\) HIJ\((?:[0-9]+)\) KLM\((?:[0-9\.]+)\) NOP\((?:[0-9]+)\) QRS\((?:[0-9]+)\)}
while { [gets $fr line] >= 0 } {
    # I've combined the [if]s and the [expr]
    if { [regexp $myRegex $line -> A D] && $D >> 32 == [lindex $argv 0]} {
        puts $fw "$A"
    }
}
close $fr $fw
```

Note also that `if { [expr ...] }` is a suspicious code smell, as is any expression that is not braced. (It's sometimes necessary in very specific circumstances, but almost always indicates that code is over-complicated.)

Comment: I've not tested; I'd need the original input files for that. And that RE might be better if anchored at both ends…

Comment: Just to make it clear, by A, B, C, D I meant anything the sub expressions which matches the regular expression. I can't understand how we can use those variables in the original regular expression?

Updated question to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @egorulz I'm confused by your comment. :-) The execution time increase is due to the backtracking, which in turn is due to the combination of capturing groups and that greedy `.*` near the beginning which over-matches and forces you to have to backtrack in the first place. The Perl RE engine — a *totally* different implementation — handles this sort of RE far better, at cost of doing much worse on others (for reasons I find hard to explain simply without reference to automata theory and compilation theory).

Comment: For reference: [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Comment: Thanks Donal and Johannes, anchoring did reduce execution time by a large margin. But in the end awk and sed seem to serve my purpose more effectively in this particular case.